# Can you integrate firebase SDK inside an iOS library?

Tags: ios, firebase

I have an iOS library and would like to integrate firebase SDK into it so that I can see crashes and other things that happened in the library. I am wondering if this is doable?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is usually best to include it from a statically linked library, but possible from a dynamic library.

See details at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/docs/firebase_in_libraries.md.

Comment: This link talks about it's doable from a technical perspective, I am wondering how to actually integrate it? because for a library there is no app bundle id which is required when integrating firebase iOS SDK.

Comment: There can still only be one instance of Firebase in the app and the bundle id is the app's bundle id.

Comment: I see what you mean, so it will conflict if the app is trying to integrate its own Firebase SDK?

Comment: Right, it's not supported to have more than one Firebase SDK in a single app.